# Services Views Multilangual

Tags: views, services

I am totally new to Drupal trying to build a CMS just as a data entry level to gather data,
I built a Service View that will retrieve the content of the node and show it as a JSON object , I have a content type with `field collection` in it , this field collection contain a `Text Field` that has `Field Translation` enabled, users can enter the data in the enabled languages. 
My service works well but it only retrieves the data according to the `Field Language` option under the `Advanced` tag when defining the service.

My Question is how can I get the data in the language I request ? Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, I have to choose 'Current User's Language' for Field Language option and enable the language detection in the URL, and I added a filter for the field language and expose it, that way i passed the locale in the URL and passed my filter as query string and got my result.